# Python re, delete from array of strings

Tags: python, regex

I have an array of strings like this:

```
/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video1.avi
/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video2.avi
/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video3.avi
```

and so on, I'd like to get only video1, video2, video3 and so on... how could I do this using regex?

Comment: Do you have to use regex? Seems like you could do this easily enough with `substring` and `indexOf` (or even `split`) and not bring regex into it at all.

Comment: `[^/]+(?=\.avi$)`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SAZvbC/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex:

```
import re

list_ = ['/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video1.avi', '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video2.avi', '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video3.avi']
regex = re.compile('[^/]+(?=\.avi$)')
result = [regex.search(path).group() for path in list_]
```

But you don't need regular expressions to get that in Python. You can use the `os` module as follows:

```
import os

list_ = ['/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video1.avi', '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video2.avi', '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video3.avi']
result = [os.path.basename(path).split('.')[0] for path in list_]
```

In both cases, you will get the following content for `result` list:

```
['video1', 'video2', 'video3']
```

Comment: Note that filenames may contain characters other than letters, digits, and underscores.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. @AhmedAbdelhameed I have edited my answer now, based on the regex you suggested in the comments. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your really need regex here. You could do,

```
s = '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video1.avi'

s.split('/')[-1][:-4]
```

But if you really want regex,

```
re.findall(r"[\w-]+(?=\.avi$)",s)[0]
```

Comment: Note that filenames may contain characters other than letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.

Answer (score 2):

if you still looking for regex.

```
myData = """/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video1.avi"""                                    
regex = re.compile(r'^/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z ]+/[a-zA-Z]+/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\..*')        
match = regex.match(myData)                                                                 
match.group(1)                                                                              
'video1'
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best answer, but it is very easy to understand.
Once you learn this, you can try to see how other solutions work.

```py
import re

lst = ['/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video1.avi',
       '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video2.avi',
       '/content/drive/My Drive/Videos/video3.avi']

new_lst = []
for line in lst:
    s = re.search('My Drive/Videos/(.*?).avi', line).group(1)
    new_lst.append(s)

print(new_lst)
```